# Why is the range of an ellipse its eigenvalues?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a two-dimensional random variable $S$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that is uniform on the unit sphere $\{z\in \mathbb R: \lVert z \rVert = 1\}$ for some norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$. Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $AA^T$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

I have been trying to find some bounds on the random variable $\lVert AS\rVert$. By simulating, I suspect that it takes values between the minimum and maximum of the eigenvalues of $A$ but I have no idea how I would go about to prove this.

So my question is: is it true and if so, how can I prove that 
$$
P\bigl(\lVert AS\rVert \in (\min\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}, \max\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\})\bigr) = 1,
$$
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

---

Here are two examples of the simulation that sparked the idea.

```
radius <- function(x){
    sqrt(rowSums(x^2))
}

## Uniform on 2d unit sphere
s <- replicate(2,rnorm(1e6))
s <- s/radius(s)

## two matrix examples
a1 <- matrix(c(20,5,5,40),2)
a2 <- matrix(c(5,4,4,5),2)

## ||AS|| 
out1 <- radius(s%*%t(a1))
out2 <- radius(s%*%t(a2))

## Compare
rbind(c(max(out1),min(out1)),eigen(a1)$values)
rbind(c(max(out2),min(out2)),eigen(a2)$values)
```

> ```
>         [,1]     [,2]
> [1,] 41.18034 18.81966
> [2,] 41.18034 18.81966
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,]    9    1
> [2,]    9    1
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|AS\|$ will take values not between the smallest and largest eigenvalues, but between the smallest and largest singular values of $A$. These are square roots of eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

In the examples you simulated it seems $A$ was symmetric and positive-definite. Under this assumption your claim is true.

Comment: Here I am assuming $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for clarifying my misconception. I just have one final request: do you have any citation for the "claims" in your answer? Or just a comment on how I would go about to prove it myself would also suffice.

Comment: @Therkel Suppose $S = \sum_i a_i v_i$ where $v_i$ are orthonormal eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\sigma_i^2$; then $\|AS\|^2 = \sum_i  |a_i \sigma_i|^2$. You can bound above by replacing all $|\sigma_i|^2$ by the largest and bound below by replacin all $|\sigma_i|^2$ by the smallest singular value